# curl with REST API

Tags: rest, curl

I want to test an API using curl for Mac.

According to the REST API documentation/forums, the URL should look like this:

```
 http://localhost:8080/sdpapi/request/?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&<your API key>&<Operation>    <Details><requester>Me</requester><subject>Test</subject><description>Testing Curl Input</description></Details></Operation>
```

Here is what I have come up with for the curl command line input:

```
curl -X POST -d "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=0...87&INPUT_DATA=<Operation><Details><requester>Me</requester><subject>Test</subject><description>Testing curl input</description></Details></Operation>" http://myserver.mydomain.org/sdpapi/request/
```

I haven't tried it yet because I am BRAND NEW to this and I'm sure there are problems. Does this look OK and should I give it a whirl?

Comment: OK I tried to run this and I'm getting curl -X: command not found.  How do I tell if this is installed?

Comment: When I type curl --manual I get the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:  curl -d "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx&INPUT_DATA=TestData.xml" http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/sdpapi/request/